# Displaying uploaded image

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to upload/resize an image using Ajax and then display it in the browser instead of saving it to a file. I'm expecting to have an image, instead I got a bunch of gibberish.

Is it doable? Or I can't and need to resort to something else like saving to a file and then take its path? Or perhaps using canvas?

Thanks for your time.

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file.php" method="Post" id="form">
  <input type="file" name="user_image">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="blah"></div>
```

Javascript

```
//using jquery-form.js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).ajaxSubmit({
    target: '#blah',
    success:  function(){}
  });
});
```

PHP

```
$img_width = imagesx($this->image);
$img_height = imagesy($this->image);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILE['user_image']['tmp_name']);
$resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
imagecopyresampled($resized_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, $img_width, $img_height);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($resized_image);
```

Comment: well echo `'<img src="$pathtoimage">';` in your php file

Comment: OP isn't saving the image so pathtoimage is irrelevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your PHP do this

```
ob_start();
// header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // fairly sure you won't need this
imagejpeg($resized_image);
echo base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
die;
```

assuming you have in HTML

```
<img id="theimage" />
```

then in JS

```
success:  function(data){
    $('#theimage').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
}
```

Comment: fix typo, ajax return bunch of rubbish

Comment: im wondering about this bit of code `data:image/jpeg;base64` can u link me to any reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the raw jpeg data using ajax.You should not perform an ajax upload but instead send the form directly to see the resized image. If this is not what you want, then you'll need to encode the raw jpeg data to a base64-encoded data url and insert that as the `src` property of an `<img>` element.